# Borrar línea en un archivo txt usando python

Tags: python-3.x

Con un archivo txt formado de frases, leo la primera línea y la escribo al final, para crear digamos un bucle con las frases, la cosa es que quiero ahora borrar la primera línea (suprimirla) para que luego el for siga por donde se ha quedado y no tengo manera de borrarlo.

```
with open ('Frases.txt', 'r+') as re:
    leer = re.readlines()
    for x in leer:
        frase1 = x
        frase = x.split('\n')
        frase = ''.join(frase)
        re.writelines(frase1)
        print (frase)
```

¿Algún consejo?
Gracias.

Ejemplo del archivo txt antes de ejecutar el for:
Linea1
Linea2
Linea3
Linea4

Ejemplo del archivo txt después de ejecutar el for y pararlo a la mitad:
Linea3
Linea4
Linea1
Linea2

Comment: Muestra un ejemplo con un archivo de entrada, el resultado deseado y el resultado obtenido para entender mejor el problema.

Comment: Ejemplo añadido, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```
def borrar(nLinea):
    f = open("x.txt", "r")
    lineas = f.readlines()
    print(lineas)
    f.close()
    
    f = open("x.txt", "w")
    
    linea=lineas[nLinea-1]
    lineas.remove(linea)
    for linea in lineas:
        f.write(linea)
    f.close()

borrar(1)
```

Simplemente indica qué línea quieres borrar. Por ejemplo, para borrar la primera línea del archivo `x.txt`, escribe `borrar(1)`.

La función primero abre en modo lectura (`"r"` de read), muestra el contenido del archivo y cierra. Posteriormente, se abre en modo escritura (`"w"` de write) y es ahí cuando borra la línea que le pases por parámetro a la función, y escribe el resultado (para ello recorre las líneas resultantes y las va escribiendo).

Suponiendo que el contenido del archivo de texto es:

```
Linea 1
Linea 2
```

Entonces el resultado de ejecutar la función es:

```
Linea 2
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.
No se si hago algo mal, pero no llego a conseguirlo. ¿puedo meterlo todo en el mismo for? o no puedo leer, escribir y borrar con el 'r+'? 
Es que lo que quiero es borrarla una vez escrita en la última línea.